# How to define a line in centimeters in Android

Tags: android, width, measure, density-independent-pixel

I'm trying to define a line in Android which measure must be 10cm wide.
I tried to put the width in mm and inches, but the results weren't satisfactory.

Also, I tried to follow this link: [draw square 3x3 cm in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035792/draw-square-3x3-cm-in-android)

Desperately, i tried to measure 10cm in dip on the screen, but not is the same length in all screens

Is there any way to get it?

Thanks

Comment: this post may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656651/difference-between-android-dimension-pt-and-dp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An `inch` or a `mm`  are unit of linear measurement on a surface, which could be a screen or a piece of paper.I'm strange if the result is not satisfactory for you.See [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/6083) for more details.

Comment: Ok, in mm work nice, the problem is with the Eclipse emulator which doesn't represente correctly the real measures.

Comment: You have to change the properties of the emulator that represents it's dpi and ... .

Comment: When I load the emulator, I select Scale to real size, is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think:
height of screen (cm) / height resolution(pixel) * 3 = 3 cm height in pixel for that screen and resolution.
width of the screen (cm) / width resoluzion(pixel) * 3 = 3 cm width in pixel for that screen and resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this.

REFER LINK TO GET dpi

nbpixel(1 inch) = densityDpi

so convert 1 cm to inch  who give approximativly 0.4 inch

nbpixel(1cm) = 0.4 * densityDpi

So for make a ligne of one cm you must draw 0.4*DPI pixel

Answer (score 0):

To draw a line of 1 cm, you must use multiple dpi (pixel density) to find the number of physical pixels.
dpi/2.54

Mobile device displays also have something which is called devicePixelRatio. You might want to check that too. When building [RealRuler](http://www.realruler.com) (online ruler) I used to multiple mobile screen width/height with that ratio to get actual size. Not sure if it impacts actual size in cm in Android.

All this is very tricky.